# Fill figure img in ul from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, datalist

I'm trying to create an Asp.Net page (without razor) to list and show some products from a database. I need image, explanation and PDF path to show from my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I have been looking for examples but many of them are about filling tables, not `ul` elements. I have seen some razor page examples but I have no idea how that works.

Note: I don't want to change this style, because I used some cool bootstrap css hover things. I don't want to mess with that, but if you think it is necessary to change it, then of course I can figure out something.

**Code:**

```
<ul class="grid cs-style-5" id="thumbs">
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
            <figcaption>
                <h4>Product Name/h4>
                <span>Explanation here.</span>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">Technical Info</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Update:**

I figured out how to do what I needed. I am posting here in case someone else needs too. I didn't use `asp:repeater` but I used `DataList`. It worked perfectly.

**Fixed Code:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
           <HeaderTemplate><ul class="grid cs-style-5" id="thumbs"></HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src='<%# Eval("urun_resim") %>' />
                          <figcaption>
                             <h4>Product Name: <%#Eval("urun_isim") %>i</h4> <br />
                             <a href='<%#Eval("urun_pdf") %>' Target="_blank"></a>
                         </figcaption>
                    </figure>
               </li>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You can generate string form back end by using string builder concept. And dump into this ul.

Comment: then how will i refer those pieces of strings to each place? that is my problem. I mean i can pull each data in back-end. my problem is showing on the page on the right places. I've seen some people use repeater and item template. I am trying to do that way but i am not sure how that works either. i am trying right now.  Thank you for your answer ^^

Comment: Repeater is good option. I agree with that solution. Even this will help you for responsive design. This is even light weight to load.

Comment: yeah i agree repeater sounds better because i also have a categorie list as dropdown list to control which products will be shown in the page. every time categorie changes, then products will be changed too. i think i got the logic of repeater. i am trying to code that right now, lets see how it will be :) thank you again ^^

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, please mark as answered as I have commented below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeater is good option. I agree with that solution. Even this will help you for responsive design. This is even light weight to load.